# How precise is .after() of java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, gwt

I am using Date validation in a Smart GWT application, where there are two fields `fromDate` and `toDate`,of `DateItem`
It shows an error message whenever the user chooses a future date, I have used `.after()` method of java.util.Date class.

Now , my question is does .after() compares the day or does it also compares the time.
How precise are `.after()` and `.before()` methods of Date class?

Comment: It compare the time and millisecond too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

It definitely also compares the time (probably to an accuracy of around 1-20ms).

**Details:**

A look at the [GWT source code for the Date implementation](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/Date.java?r=9506) can answer your question:

```
public boolean after(Date when) {
    return getTime() > when.getTime();
}

public boolean before(Date when) {
  return getTime() < when.getTime();
}

...

public long getTime() {
    return (long) jsdate.getTime();
}
```

Here, you see, that the `after()`- and `before()`-functions are mapped straight to a comparison between two [`getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) calls on an underlying JavaScript date-object. Since JavaScript's `getTime()` returns time in milliseconds, that is the best accuracy that you can hope for in GWT. Now, I don't know if all browsers actually do report time at the millisecond level or even if all of them report at the same accuracy but if I understand your question correctly, you are only worried about day vs. time. So, to answer that, it does compare time also and I would say you should always be able to expect accuracy that is much better than 1s, probably around 1ms to 20ms.

If you would like to check with day-accuracy only, you have to compare the values returned by `getYear()`, `getMonth()`, and `getDate()` (**not** `getDay()`!!!) yourself, e.g. like this:

```
public boolean isLaterDay(Date date, Date reference) {
    if (date.getYear () > reference.getYear ()) return true;
    if (date.getYear () < reference.getYear ()) return false;
    if (date.getMonth() > reference.getMonth()) return true;
    if (date.getMonth() < reference.getMonth()) return false;
    return (date.getDate() > reference.getDate());
}
```

**Note**: This answer focuses specifically on GWT, not Java in general. In plain Java, I would expect that you will probably get the same or potentially even much higher resolution than with GWT. But since I don't have the source-code available there, I don't know for sure. Also, the `getYear()` and such functions are deprecated in regular Java and shouldn't be used there anymore (use `Calendar.get(...)` instead), but GWT doesn't implement Calendar yet.

Comment: Thanks, I was using java.util.Date and not GWT's date. I saw the definition of .after() and apparently it checks,right down to the milliseconds, which basically screws my functionality. Need to write my own method like the one you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @KanwaljeetSingh If you are writing a GWT app, the GWT compiler will implement java.util.Date with exactly the source-code that I linked to above, there isn't really a "GWT's date" (or better: java.util.Date **is** GWT's date). Because when you run the app in your browser later, Java isn't available any more, so everything has to be converted to JavaScript.